# How to debug input for a placeholder?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I ran the [retrain.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py) program for transfer learning of the InceptionV3 network. I am now trying to open the saved model and run an image through so I can view the final tensor. However, I am getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float and shape [?,299,299,3]
     [[node Placeholder (defined at /Users/jake/.spyder-py3/imageclassification/testopen:18) ]]
```

Below is my code. It ran fine until I added line the last line.

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

sess=tf.Session()    

saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph('/Users/jake/Desktop/Freckle/retrain_tmp/_retrain_checkpoint.meta')
saver.restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint('/Users/jake/Desktop/Freckle/retrain_tmp'))
image_path = '/Users/jake/.spyder-py3/imageclassification/flower_photos/dandelion/8181477_8cb77d2e0f_n.jpg'

graph = tf.get_default_graph()
writer = tf.summary.FileWriter('/Users/jake/Desktop/Freckle/transfer-learning-tmp', sess.graph)

input_height = 299
input_width = 299
input_depth = 3
jpeg_data = tf.placeholder(tf.string, name='DecodeJPGInput')
decoded_image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(jpeg_data, channels=input_depth)
decoded_image_as_float = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(decoded_image, tf.float32)
decoded_image_4d = tf.expand_dims(decoded_image_as_float, 0)
resize_shape = tf.stack([input_height, input_width])
resize_shape_as_int = tf.cast(resize_shape, dtype=tf.int32)
resized_image = tf.image.resize_bilinear(decoded_image_4d,
                                           resize_shape_as_int)

image_data = tf.gfile.GFile(image_path, 'rb').read()
resized_input_tensor = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, input_height, input_width, 3], name='resized_input_tensor')

resized_input_values = sess.run(resized_image, {jpeg_data: image_data})
#output_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('final_result')
output_tensor = graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')

#THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS A BUG
final_values = sess.run(output_tensor,feed_dict={resized_input_tensor: resized_input_values})
```

I investigated the placeholder in the console, below are the readouts:

```
graph.get_tensor_by_name('final_result:0')
Out[17]: <tf.Tensor 'final_result:0' shape=(?, 5) dtype=float32>

resized_input_tensor
Out[18]: <tf.Tensor 'resized_input_tensor:0' shape=(?, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>

np.shape(resized_input_values)
Out[19]: (1, 299, 299, 3)

graph.get_operation_by_name('Placeholder')
Out[21]: <tf.Operation 'Placeholder' type=Placeholder>

graph.get_operation_by_name('Placeholder').values()
Out[22]: (<tf.Tensor 'Placeholder:0' shape=(?, 299, 299, 3) dtype=float32>,)

resized_input_values.dtype
Out[32]: dtype('float32')
```

Since the `InvalidArgumentError` mentions a `'Placeholder'`, I tried the following:

```
x = graph.get_operation_by_name('Placeholder')

final_values = sess.run(output_tensor,feed_dict={x: resized_input_values})
```

Which gave the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-28-84a55042c4a2>", line 1, in <module>
    final_values = sess.run(output_tensor,feed_dict={x: resized_input_values})

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 950, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)

  File "/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1116, in _run
    'Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: ' + e.args[0])

TypeError: Cannot interpret feed_dict key as Tensor: Can not convert a Operation into a Tensor.
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the line marked with `#THIS IS THE LINE THAT THROWS A BUG` (throws an error?), what is the actual message that you get? Is it possible that `resized_input_values` is `tf.int32` but `resized_input_tensor` expects `tf.float32`?

Comment: It give the `InvalidArgumentError` at the top of the post. Would you like me to post the full traceback?

Comment: I just ran `resized_input_values.dtype` which gave me `Out[32]: dtype('float32')`

Comment: Ah of course, sorry... Right, then maybe you are missing the initial batch dimension... Try maybe `feed_dict={resized_input_tensor: resized_input_values[np.newaxis]}`?

Comment: Running `final_values = sess.run(output_tensor,feed_dict={resized_input_tensor:resized_input_values[np.newaxis]})` gives `ValueError: Cannot feed value of shape (1, 1, 299, 299, 3) for Tensor 'resized_input_tensor:0', which has shape '(?, 299, 299, 3)'`

Comment: Which makes me think that there is some connection missing that feeds `resized_input_tensor` into the main graph. There is placeholder called 'Placeholder', which seems to show up in the `InvalidArgumentError`. I just can't figure out why it doesn't cause an issue until I try  to get the final output...

Comment: Ohh, right, of course, I'm sorry, I'm kind of slow today... You were on the right track, instead of `x = graph.get_operation_by_name('Placeholder')` you have to do `x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')`, then `feed_dict={x: resized_input_values})`... keys to the `feed_dict` value should be tensors, not operations.

Comment: *Also, I know that a better way of expressing gratitude is by answering questions, but thank you anyway!

Comment: Wooooo! Thank you! That last comment is the correct answer, which I will mark as "correct" if you post it as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it almost right, but the keys to the `feed_dict` should be tensor objects, not operations, so you should do:

```
x = graph.get_tensor_by_name('Placeholder:0')
final_values = sess.run(output_tensor, feed_dict={x: resized_input_values})
```